Can 2 points in $\mathbb{C}^2$ with distances strictly less than $1/\sqrt{2}$ from $(1, 0)$, $(0, 1)$ respectively be collinear with the origin?
Problem: Suppose that 2 points $P, Q \in \mathbb{C}^2$ have distance strictly less than $1/\sqrt{2}$ from $(1, 0)$, $(0, 1)$ respectively. Can the origin, $P$ and $Q$ be collinear?
Remark: The answer is "negative" for the analogous problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $P$ and $Q$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respective distances from $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ strictly less than $1/\sqrt{2}$, then $P$ (resp. $Q$) lies inside the circle centred at $(1, 0)$ (resp. $(0, 1)$), which we shall name as $\mathcal{C}$ (resp. $\mathcal{D})$. The line $y = x$ is a common tangent of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ at the point $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$. The line $y = -x$ is tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ at $(1/\sqrt{2}),-1/\sqrt{2})$ and is tangent to $\mathcal{D} $ at $(-1\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$.
The line $OP$, say $y = mx$, has gradient $-1 < m < 1$. The line $OQ$ is either the $y$-axis or a line $y = kx$ whose gradient satisfies $|k| > 1$. Therefore the gradient of OP and OQ are distinct and thus these lines are also distinct, so that $P$, $P$ and $Q$ are not collinear.
The problem in $\mathbb{C}^2$ involves geometry in $4$ real dimensions.

Let us prove that the answer is also negative in $\Bbb C^2$.
We are looking for three complex numbers $u,v,\lambda$ such that
$$|u-1|^2+|v|^2<\frac12\quad\text{and}\quad|\lambda u|^2+|\lambda v-1|^2<\frac12.$$
Let us first deal with the second inequation. Given $r:=|u|$, $R:=|v|$, and $t:=|\lambda|$, the quantity $|\lambda v-1|$ is minimal when $\lambda=\frac{\overline v}{r^2+R^2}$, and the second inequality is then equivalent to
$$\frac{R^2r^2}{(r^2+R^2)^2}+\left|\frac{R^2}{r^2+R^2}-1\right|^2<\frac12,$$
i.e. $$r<R.$$
Similarly, in the first equation, given $|u|$, the quantity $|u-1|$ is minimal when $u=r$. But the inequations
$$0\le r<R,\quad(r-1)^2+R^2<\frac12$$
are incompatible, since they imply
$$0>(r-1)^2+r^2-\frac12=2\left(r-\frac12\right)^2.$$
